# Is kin-slaying not sin on the Iron Islands?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

**Season 6 Episode 5 Spoilers**

I believed kin-slaying in *Game of Thrones* is a big sin in the North. And all the Northerners respect guest right and see kin-slaying as a big crime.
However in Season 6 Episode 5 ("The Door"), Euron publicly accepts that he killed his brother, still he got selected as King by Kingsmoot and after that he says "lets kill my niece and nephew".

Shouldn't the other Iron Islanders have opposed him? Or are Iron Islanders' customs different from the rest of the North in that regard?

Update:- Kin-slaying means killing your own kin/family. Not to be confused with kingslaying means killing your useless king.

Comment: Perhaps Euron will fill the roll Quentyn did in the books.....

Comment: @Skooba why not just the role that Victarion plays?

Comment: Small point of contention. The Iron Islands are a distinct kingdom, NOT a part of the North.

Comment: @kuhl just speculating...

Comment: @Skooba Thinking aboutbit more, you might be right.  It'd be a good way to get Dany ships without needing to deal with a troublesome marriage.

Comment: @kuhl true. she "takes what is hers" and wants to "break the wheel"

Comment: @DavidGrinberg kinslaying (no g)..family members, not kings (although in this case the first offense mentioned would be both).

Comment: My eye first led me to wonder "kin-slaying" or "kins-laying".  Whatever.

Comment: @EricTowers Jamie Lannister fits both those titles :P

Comment: No need for "-' in [Kinslaying](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Kinslaying)

Comment: How do you know it will be Euron who swings the sword/axe to kill them? Mayhaps one of his men will be the one to do it. Also, Kinslaying is bad, but breaking guest right is even worse...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Ironlanders are a little different than the rest of the westerners in that they believe to truly deserve something, you need to have paid "the iron price".

In this case, the Ironlanders would have responded positively for a few reasons:

- The current king was not really doing anything special and they were being viewed as weak which would have been insulting to them.
- Euron saw this and did what he thought needed to be done, hence paying "the iron price" by seeing something that he wanted and seizing it.
- The other 2 options for "king" were not really seen to be desirable, one being a woman and the other someone they viewed as a weak, traitorous eunuch.

Comment: On the other hand, Euron suggests they hand a zillion ships to Daenerys without her ever having to pay an iron price - something perhaps even more humiliating than bending the knee, and gets a lot of applause. Hmmph.

Comment: @einpoklum They are not complete oafs I think. They acknowledge the power dragons have. Isn't that why the Targaryens were the first house to which the Ironborn bent the knee?

Comment: @einpoklum I'd say fire and blood is the ultimate iron price.

Comment: Westerners? Who are those? Did you mean "Westerosi"?

Comment: @kuhl: She did not go through any fire and blood to get the Ironborn's ships, they would be nothing but a tribute. "Oh, that guy seems accomplished, let's build ships and give it to him for free".

Comment: Guess where Theon and Yara is going? Meeren!! They have some best ships.

Comment: @einpoklum I feel that its a little different than what you make it out to be. Euron is not "gifting" the fleet to her. He intends on marrying her and essentially using her army to take Westeros.

Comment: I think it is completely out-of-cultural-character for the Iron-Born to: 1. Use other people to do their fighting for them 2. Put their ships at the disposal of other people  3. Base their political plans on offering dowries for marriage. 4. View a political alliance with a distant ruler in Essos, even if it results in a conquest of Westeros, as an exciting achievement.

Comment: @einpoklum the Ironborn are idiots, even in the books.